# Closed form of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2^{3n}}{2^{4n}+2^{2n}} $?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, closed-form

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2^{3n}}{2^{4n}+2^{2n}}
$$
I know it converges thanks to [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%20%282%5E%283n%29%29/%282%5E%284n%29%20%2b2%5E%282n%29%29%20from%201%20to%20infinity), but want to know exactly what it converges to. I can calculate the decimal, but don't know how to begin finding the closed form.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/298867/59379), the sum equals to

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{2^{-k}}{1+2^{-2k}} = \frac14 ( \vartheta_3(1/2)^2 - 1)$$

where $\vartheta_3(q)$ is a [Jacobi Theta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theta_function#Jacobi_theta_function).

Numerically, WA (using expression `EllipticTheta[3, 0, 1/2]^2 - 1` ) gives a number $$0.8830930035647435252069892946651177983893073315219718$$ which does match the value of the sum I computed so far.

**Update**

One can also express the sum in terms of [Dedekind Eta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_eta_function).  Let $H = \{\; z \in \mathbb{C} : \Im z > 0\;\}$ be the
upper half complex plane. For $\tau \in H$, we know:
$$\vartheta_3(e^{i\pi\tau}) = \frac{\eta\left(\frac{\tau+1}{2}\right)^2}{\eta(\tau+1)}$$ This implies the sum has an alternate closed-form (a little bit ugly for my taste):

$$\frac14 \left[\;\eta\left(\frac12+ i\frac{\log 2}{2\pi}\right)^4 \eta\left(1+i\frac{\log 2}{\pi}\right)^{-2} - 1 \;\right]$$

On WA, one can evaluate this alternate closed-form numerically by entering:

`(DedekindEta[1/2 + I*Log(2)/(2*Pi)]^4/DedekindEta[1 + I*Log(2)/(Pi)]^2 - 1)/4`

As expected, this give you the same number as above.

Comment: Other than the Jacobi Theta function representation, is there no other closed form?